# Creating a missile that fires in a ever changing direction

Tags: c++, vector, 2d, velocity, angle

Ok, I'm a programming student at university and I've came across this issue while creating my 2D Star Wars X-Wing Game. The Ship is constantly changing direction to avoid incoming TieFighters and I have been able to create a missile in front of the X-Wing.

The issue is that I don't know how to fire the missile in the direction the ship is facing.

Code for placing missile:

```
if (pInputs->KeyPressed(DIK_SPACE))
{
    Vector2D missileDirection;  //Section needs fixed as missile spawns inside ship and destroys it.
    missileDirection.setBearing(m_angle, 100);
    Vector2D missilePosition = m_position + missileDirection;
    FlakShell* pFlakShell = new FlakShell;
    pFlakShell->Initialise(missilePosition, m_angle, m_pParticles);
    Game::instance.m_objects.AddItem(pFlakShell, true);
}
```

This is the velocity for the `FlakShell(missile)`:

```
m_velocity.set(0, 0);
```

and this is the code I have to make it move:

```
m_velocity += m_velocity * 1.5f * frametime;
m_position += m_velocity * frametime; //Position is equal to velocity * frametime
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: If you want a tracking missile, take a vector between the current missile's position and the target, normalize it, then multiply by the scalor velocity of the missile. If you do the subtraction wrong, you will get a missile that always runs away though so beware :)

Comment: No, It's not a homing missile, it's a simple missile that fires in the direction that the ship is facing

Comment: Just create a [unit vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) in the direction of your ship and add some multiple of that vector to the position of the missile. Unit vectors are easily solved from an angle, basic trig. I'll leave it to you to figure that you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you already have the right code, but you are missing a scaling factor to move the missle away from the ship:

```
float ScalingFactor = 100.f; //Just a guess...
Vector2D missilePosition = m_position + missileDirection*ScalingFactor;
```